# How to make a bot that sends a message in a server different from where the command was received?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is my full code. I'm using Replit to create a Discord bot.

```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
# from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

global channelSaved
channelSaved = "default"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")
  print(client.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global channelSaved
  if message.content.__contains__("!!reverse_"):
    revmsg = message.content.replace("!!reverse_", "")
    await message.channel.send(revmsg[::-1])
    
  if message.content.__contains__("!!saychannel_"):
    channelSaved = message.content.replace("!!saychannel_", "")
    
  if message.content.__contains__("!!say_"):
    saymsg = message.content.replace("!!say_", "")
    await message.channel.send(saymsg)
    print(channelSaved)

keep_alive()
my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Basically, I want to make it so that if you DM the bot with "!!saychannel_1234567890", with "1234567890" being the channel ID, it will save the channel ID to the channelSaved variable. Then if you say "!!say_Hello world", it will say "Hello world" in the channel specified by the channelSaved variable. I don't really know how to do this though. I'm mostly having trouble with getting the bot to say something in another Discord channel that isn't where it got the command.

I tried replacing the message.channel.send() in the "!!say" command with message.channelSaved.send() but it didn't work. It just gave me an error saying that 'Message' object has no attribute 'channelSaved'.

And by the way, if there's a better way to write these commands, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the channel object from the client first and send the message to that channel

```py
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
# from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

global channelSaved
channelSaved = "default"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")
    print(client.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global channelSaved
    if message.content.__contains__("!!reverse_"):
        revmsg = message.content.replace("!!reverse_", "")
        await message.channel.send(revmsg[::-1])
    
    if message.content.__contains__("!!saychannel_"):
        channelSaved = message.content.replace("!!saychannel_", "")
    
    if message.content.__contains__("!!say_"):
        saymsg = message.content.replace("!!say_", "")
        chan = client.get_channel(channelSaved)
        if chan:
            await chan.send(saymsg)
        print(channelSaved)

keep_alive()
my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']
client.run(my_secret)
```